# simple unsigned long long conversion from array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have an 8 byte counter which I am trying to increment. I later want to convert it to an unsigned long long value. But the value after conversion throws error. Is this some endian problem or this is wrongly done?
Please advise.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned          char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     int uint16_t;
typedef unsigned           int uint32_t;

#define COUNTER_LENGTH 8

typedef struct {
    uint8_t data[8];
}count_t;

static void incrementCtr(count_t* count) {
    int i;
    for (i = sizeof(count->data) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (++count->data[i] != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    count_t count;
    count_t *counter;
    counter = &count;
    memset(counter ,0,sizeof(*counter));

    incrementCtr(counter);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < COUNTER_LENGTH; i++){
        printf("counter->data[%d] = %02X\n", i, counter->data[i]);
    }

    unsigned long long  aa = 0;
    int m;
    for(m = 0; m< COUNTER_LENGTH; m++){
        aa = aa |(counter->data[m]<< m*8);
    }
    printf("aa = %llu\n", aa);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh?

If you're certain that the `unsigned long long` is big enough, then why are you bothering with the manual implementation? Why not just use an `unsigned long long` variable?

There's some brokenness in your loop; the expression `(counter->data[m] << m * 8)` does not have type `unsigned long long` so will likely drop a lot of bits.

Use something like this:

```
for(m = 0; m < COUNTER_LENGTH; ++m)
{
  a <<= 8;
  a |= counter->data[m];
}
```

The above should also be endian-safe; it always OR:s in the most significant byte first (as determined by the `counter` representation).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I need to pass the "unsigned long long" counter value into a crypto library which takes unsigned char* input. Therefore the conversion.